# Generating random terrain in Blender3D

Tags: blender

I tried finding a python script in google that will generate a random terrain when the game starts (or each time a the player advances to a new scene) but all the tools I found are for creating a terrain to render it, not for the game mode.

Any idea how/where to find one?

(I'm assuming that since Blender3D has game programming capabilities, it is OK for someone to ask in SO)

Answer (score 4):

Is this link related?

http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?t=77794

To generate terrain (height map) the algorithm is pretty simple (fractal plasma), something like this algorithm (Java):

http://www.sinc.stonybrook.edu/stu/jseyster/plasma/

If you Google search for "fractal plasma python" you might find some example code.

Answer (score 2):

I've not really worked much with the game engine, but how about generating a random cloud texture and using that to displace the model? Wouldn't that be easier?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reprogram most of the python scripts available to generate terrain for rendering to generate terrain for your game... is there a specific thing you *need* from the script to make it suitable for realtime gameplay instead of a static render?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to achieve this is to cheat a little. Instead of actually generating random terrain make a random cloud texture (not sure how to do that with phyton) and then make the displace modifier use that texture and that's it! I'm not sure how easier it could be.